# webpack doesn't load scss files?

Tags: angular, webpack

I've this 4 files inside a `signin` folder.

```
signin.component.ts
signin.module.ts
signin.style.scss
signin.template.html
```

In `signin.style.scss` I've declared to import two files located in `node_modules`:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

Nevertheless, something is wrong when I look at locaded resources on browser:

My Signin component is like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'signin',
  styleUrls: [ './signin.style.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './signin.template.html'
})
export class Signin implements OnInit {
```

Nevertheless neither `signin.style.scss`, neither other imports (`"../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables"` and `"../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins"`) are loaded on browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loader in webpack.

```
{test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]}
```